# Is using "\\\\" to match '\' with Regex in Java the most Readable Way?

Tags: java, regex, readability

I know that the following works but it is not that readable, is there any way to make it more readable in the code itself without the addition of a comment?

```
//Start her off
String sampleregex = "\\\\";
if (input.matches(sampleregex))
   //do something
//do some more
```

Comment: Regular expressions are almost always ugly. Understand this and move on.

Comment: @Savvas yes I did mean that thank you, edited question to fix this.

Comment: @Bryon That seems to be the best answer so far, why don't you make it an official answer as it seems quite popular

Comment: `Really formulate questions this way? Really?`

Comment: @java.is.for.desktop Does the title describe my problem in a clear way? I think so. Is the point of a title to get people's attention and look at your problem? Definitely. Did my title work? As of this post 81 views in 25 minutes, it appears it did. Would I be dumped by Elaine for being a question talker? Quite possibly.

Comment: The reason you have to use four backslashes is because you're encoding the backslash twice. Once for inclusion in a string, where it is part of an escape sequence, and so needs to be doubled. Then again for inclusion in a RE, where it is a special character and needs to be escaped. 1 x 2 x 2 = 4.

Comment: @Byron they're only *truly* ugly in languages that insist on double-quotes and don't support the `/x` modifier.

Comment: Now that you've gotten some eyeballs and answers, please consider changing the title to match something more google-able and less sensationalist.

Comment: @Nathan Fellman complete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean `"\\\\"` instead of `"////"`:

You could escape it with `\Q` and `\E`, which removes one layer of backslashes: `"\\Q\\\E"`, but that's not that much better. You could also use `Pattern.quote("\\")` to have it escaped at runtime. But personally, I'd just stick with `"\\\\"`.

(As an aside, you need four of them because `\` is used to escape things in both the regex engine and in Java Strings, so you need to escape once so the regex engine knows you're not trying to scape anything else (so that's `\\`); then you need to escape both of those so Java knows you're not escaping something in the string (so that's `\\\\`)).

Answer (score 6):

Why not

```
if (input.contains("\\")) {
}
```

since you simply appear to be looking for a backward slash ?

Comment: because you don't always try to match a single slash. he tried to say that when you do try to match something with one slash you need 4 of them in the string. and he actually meant the backslash not the forward one...

Comment: My answer still stands, subject to \ escaping - now changed to reflect the changed question.

Comment: sorry I didn't make it clear in the question, I'm looking for more than just a single single backslash. The other portions of the regex just happen to be readable so I omitted them from my sample code.

Answer (score 2):

`/` is not a regex metacharacter, so the regex string `"/"` matches a single slash, and `"////"` matches four in a row.

I imagine you meant to ask about matching a single backslash, rather than a forward slash, in which case, no, you need to put `"\\\\"` in your regex string literal to match a single backslash.  (And I needed to enter eight to make four show up on SO--damn!)

Answer (score 2):

My solution is similiar to Soldier.moth's but with a twist.  Create a constants file which contains common regular expressions and keep adding to it.  The expressions as constants can even be combined providing a layer of abstraction to building regular expressions, but in the end they still often end up messy.

```
public static final String SINGLE_BACKSLASH = "\\\\";
```

Answer (score 1):

The one solution I've thought of is to do

```
String singleSlash = "\\\\";
if(input.matches(singleSlash))
   //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using better names for your variables and constants, and composing them step by step is a good way to do without comments, for example:

```
final string backslash = "\\";
final string regexEscapedBackslash = backslash + backslash;

if (input.matches(regexEscapedBackslash)) {
    ...
```